# Explanation of ST_GeomFromText and ST_ConvexHull?

Tags: mysql, math

Given the places table, write a select statement which returns only one column area and consists of a single row: the area of the convex hull. It is guaranteed that the resulting area is greater than 0.
For the following table places

```
x   y
0   0
1   2
2   1
5   1
5   2
```

the output should be

area
6.5

```
CREATE PROCEDURE solution()
BEGIN
     SELECT ST_Area(ST_ConvexHull(ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT("MULTIPOINT (",GROUP_CONCAT(x,' ',y SEPARATOR ", "),")"),0)))  AS area
     FROM places;
END
```

Comment: Please add places table definition as text and what actually happened when you CALLed solution. Also did the procedure compile - you don't appear to be setting delimiters.

Comment: When setting delimiters the procedure compiles and when CALLed produces the desired outcome. - on my local server using mysqlworkbench , also see https://dbfiddle.uk/fK8Yxrzi note dbfiddle does not require that delimiters are set and wherever you are compiling from may not either. see manual for more https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: But I'm not clear what you mean by 'can anyone explain what's going on here'..

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the innermost string concatenation:

```sql
CONCAT("MULTIPOINT (",GROUP_CONCAT(x,' ',y SEPARATOR ", "),")")
```

This produces:

```
MULTIPOINT (0 0, 1 2, 2 1, 5 1, 5 2)
```

which is the [WKT (Well Known Text)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-data-formats.html#gis-wkt-format) representation of a [MULTIPOINT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-class-multipoint.html), which is a collection of [POINT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-class-point.html)s.

[`ST_GeomFromText()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-wkt-functions.html#function_st-geomfromtext):

> Constructs a geometry value of any type using its WKT representation and SRID.

[`ST_ConvexHull(g)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-operator-functions.html#function_st-convexhull):

> Returns a geometry that represents the convex hull of the geometry value g.
>
> This function computes a geometry's convex hull by first checking whether its vertex points are colinear. The function returns a linear hull if so, a polygon hull otherwise. This function processes geometry collections by extracting all vertex points of all components of the collection, creating a MultiPoint value from them, and computing its convex hull.

Additional info on [Convex Hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull).

The value returned from ST_ConvexHull() is:

```
POLYGON((0 0,5 1,5 2,1 2,0 0))
```

[`ST_Area()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-polygon-property-functions.html#function_st-area):

> Returns a double-precision number indicating the area of the Polygon or MultiPolygon argument, as measured in its spatial reference system. For arguments of dimension 0 or 1, the result is 0. If the argument is an empty geometry the return value is 0. If the argument is NULL the return value is NULL.
>
> The result is the sum of the area values of all components for a geometry collection. If a geometry collection is empty, its area is returned as 0.

The below image shows the original polygon in black and the convex hull in dashed yellow:

[image: complex (non-simple) polygon overlaid with convex hull]

This [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HXf-XYdC) shows how the spatial type changes as the query is built up.